# Stuck in loop during std::getline and std::cin during while loop

Tags: c++, stdin

So I'm new to C++ and I'm supposed to get a vector in integers from stdin. I tried using std::cin and std::getline and other functions, but everytime I try entering a sentinel (e.g. not an integer) or when there is a "count" variable that reaches an increment, I end up in a hung state. I can enter inputs, but no more print statements (e.g. "std::cout << "added") appear after the count has reached. I'm not sure what went wrong with the std::cin.

```
std::vector<int> Game::getIds() {
    std::vector<int> cards; 
    int x =0 ;  
    std::string mystr; 
    bool keepGoing = true; 
    int count = 0; 
    while (keepGoing) {
        std::getline(std::cin, mystr); 
        std::stringstream sstream(mystr); 
        while (sstream >> x) { 
            std::cout << "added" << x << std::endl; 
            cards.push_back(x); 
        }
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            keepGoing = false; 
            std::cout <<"fail";
            std::cin.clear(); 
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
            return cards;
        }
        ++count; 
        if (count == 5) return cards; 
    } 
    return cards; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `while (std::cin >> x)`?

Comment: I tried that too but I run into the same issue where if I provide a sentinel or "CTRL+D" or a character, my terminal stops working. I can keep carriage returning and providing new input but I can't break out (even if I use "breaks").

Comment: What output do you exactly expecting from your hypothesis?

Comment: So I'm trying to get a series of integers from stdin and put them into a vector. Of course, I would need to do some defensive programming against bad inputs and the like, but I can't even get to that when my cin just hangs. After entering 5 integers and carriage returning them, I expected that the "count" variable will reach 5 and break out of the while loop and function for me. I tried breaking out of this "while" loop in so many ways, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) controls input from a stream buffer, which put your input characters in a stream buffer, then it was passed to `getline`.
`cin` ends input when you signaled `EOF` with `Ctrl+D`,  `Ctrl+Z`, or `Enter`.
See this link
[detecting end of input with cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420352/detecting-end-of-input-with-cin).

[getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) extracts characters from input and appends them to str until it meet one of the end conditions,
in your situaton the end condition is the endline character `'\n'`, because the default delimeter is the endline character.
You may define your own delimeter `getline(intput, str, $your_delemeter)` , and do a little experiment.